# React js Warning: Don't set the props property of the component. Mutate the existing props object instead

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in react js & getting the following warning, Please help me to fix/understand this, will such a warnings leads to an performance issue??

```
 ==>node_modules\React\lib\warning.js:37 
 Warning: Don't set the props property of the component. Mutate the existing props object instead.
```

Comment: You should add the code that causes this warning

Comment: yeah, i came here to see what caused this warning and that's harder than it should be, No line number or files are given in the warning, so when i updated from 0.12.x to 0.13.x i get this error - where I have no idea .....  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Props are meant to be immutable. If you want to change values of a component, use **state** instead.

If you do something like this, React will yell at you

```js
var c = <Component />
c.props.foo = x; // bad
c.props.bar = y; // also bad
```

Instead do

```js
var c = <Component foo="x" bar="y" />
```

[read more from the reactjs docs here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)